# How to fix 'Duplicate class found' error after flutter upgrade?

Tags: flutter

I did flutter upgrade and now when I build the same apps in Android studio which were working fine before are failing with following build error. What should I do ?

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
```

Comment: did you do a flutter clean after upgrade?

Comment: Yes I did but that didn't work. Eventually I createted a new project from scratch and error is gone.